# Site creation in SharePoint designer 2010 missing options (Quick Launch, Top Navigation)

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When I create a new subsite via the WebUI there are options for placement of the site on the QuickLaunch of the parent site, and if the Top Navigation bar should be inherited.

How do i set those options when creating a new subsite from SharePoint Designer 2010?

Manually adding the site to the TopNav and QuickLaunch is error prone and could lead to errors with respect to the security trimming of the Menus (Top and Quick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SPD 2007 you would have to go back to the site and manually update these settings from the Navigation options within Site Settings.

I am not 100% that the same is true of 2010 but due to the fact that you are asking this question I would supect that is the case there too.

Its worth noting that SPD is a design tool and it does not set out to replace the functionality of the browser UI.

Comment: Thanks, one would think that with the Designer the whole structure of a SharePoint sitecollection can be managed/edited, but it is not. Only a site (SPWebs) can be designed / altered. The global structure not :(